# How I Can periodically check the database using JSP , inorder to check the current date is the date that stored in the database?

Tags: android, mysql, jsp

Hi am creating a library application that integrated with android mobiles using jsp, so I need to check the return date of issued book periodically, and inform the client or mobile users that the book has to be return immediately. How I can accomplish this through JSP? should I code it in mobile side or web side?

Comment: You can create scheduler for your requirement which runs with given interval.

Comment: check `quartz` api for scheduler.

Comment: Where I can use this? quartz api? in web application ? will it run background?

Comment: @AjithKumarPV yes it will be in backend, it will run based on the period you define, say, every 4 hours, and checks db for exceeded books, and from there, you continue with your logic/approach to deliver that notification to the user.